# counterfactual "didn’t happen" vs. "hadn't happened"

Tags: subjunctives

In the following sentences, should "didn’t happen" or "hadn't happened" be used?

> Sales have gone down, and obviously we’d prefer it if that didn’t happen / hadn't happened.

> Sales have gone down, and obviously we wish that didn’t happen / hadn't happened.

I thought "hadn't happened" is correct because the sentences are about counterfactual past scenarios. However, the Longman Dictionary uses "didn't happen" in the first sentence. Is it an error or an examlpe of language change?

Answer (score 1):

Both verb forms are fine. It depends on the intended meaning. Sales went down *in the past*, but...

> 1: *...we’d prefer it if that **didn’t happen in the future***
> OR
> 2: *...we’d prefer it if that **hadn’t happened in the past***

So #1 looks forward optimistically, hoping the future will be different to the past, whereas #2 looks back regretfully, wishing the past had been different.

Comment: _We'd prefer it if that didn't happen_ could also mean _if that didn't happen_ **often** (if it were not the usual state of affairs).

Comment: But surely even if we weaken the aversion (negated preference) so we don't mind it happening ***sometimes***, using ***didn't*** ALWAYS means we're talking about an unwanted *potential* future (and ***hadn't*** always refers to the unwanted *actual* past).

Comment: I didn't exactly mean _we don't mind it happening sometimes_, but _we'd prefer it not to be a habitual occurrence_. There seems to me to be a difference, though it's not easy to explain it.

Comment: We'd rather it ***hadn't*** been habitual in the ***past***, OR we'd rather it ***didn't*** become habitual in the ***future***. The same ***have/do = past/future*** distinction applies even if there's no explicit ***if-*** clause potentially referencing a "counterfactual" (to use OP's terminology).

Comment: Is this OK? "Sales **went** down, and obviously we’d prefer it if that *hadn't happened*."

Comment: @Apollyon: [Obviously!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sales+went+up%2Csales+went+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)